# Silicon detectors with charge division?

Tags: particle-detectors

Instead of using double-sided silicon strip detectors to gain a 2D position resolution sometimes a one-sided strip detector is used with resistive charge division, where the signal at one strip is split to two readout channels using the ratio of the signals' amplitudes.

In this context, something like this is said occasionally:

> The choice to use resistive charge division for position sensitivity [...] was necessary to reduce the number of electronics channels while still covering a large solid angle [...].

In my opinion the number of electronic channels is the same for a double-sided detector with e.g. 4 strips on each side (which are readout by one channel each) and a single-sided detector with 4 strips (which are readout by two channels each). I do not recognize any benefit here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with a measurement accuracy requirement and a detector size.

- If each strip is independent, with no inter-strip coupling, then all you know is that a particular one was hit: your measurement error is $w/\sqrt(12)$. From that, you can determine how small each strip needs to be.
- if the strips are coupled, you can compute an estimated hit position. How accurate that will be depends on noise, etc, but generally it’s a lot more accurate than “somewhere on strip 7”. That allows the strips to be wider while still meeting your accuracy goal. And that means fewer strips, hence fewer channels.

Comment: Ok, so it is referring to different strip widths. I was assuming a choice between single-sided resistive strips and the same amount of double-sided non-resistive strips